# Jquery how to get the element of siblings child in a table td

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Hi am trying to get the value from `td.a > a` which is triggered form `td.b > b`

my html markup

```
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="ha">
        <a class="A"> a value </a>
      </div>
    </td>
      <td>
      <a> <span> b value </span> </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

here i need to get the `b value`  by clicking the `class A` 
i tried to get it by jquery is

```
$('.A').on('click', function(){
      $(this).parent().find('td').next();
   })
```

I struck here is there any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
   $('.A').on('click', function(){
      $(this).parent().next('td').find('span').text();
   });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/JJvvz/)

According to your new edit, you have to use `.closest()`

Just try,

```
   $('.A').on('click', function () {
       alert($(this).closest('td').next('td').find('span').text());
   })
```

### [DEMO I](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/JJvvz/3/)

Comment: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JJvvz/2/) and can you tell me for this case..

Answer (score 1):

Write:

```
$('.A').on('click', function () {
    alert($(this).closest("td").next().find("span").text());
});
```

[**Updated demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/JJvvz/4/)

Answer (score 0):

> Try this:

```
 $('.A').on('click', function(){
     $("td").siblings().find('span').text();
   });
```